# How to unit test mocking SQLAlchemy engine in Python for an update query

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a function called `update_worker_data`. This simply updates a table in PostgreSQL, however if the row does not exist in the db, it then inserts it. This is checked by getting the `rowcount` after the query is executed:

```
def update_worker_data(db: engine, data: List[dict]) -> int:
    """Update the data for the modifiable table.

    Args:
    ----------
    * db(engine): db engine
    * date(List[dict]): data to either be updated or inserted  

    Returns:
    ----------
    * row_count(int): amount of rows updated and inserted 

    """
    update_query = """
    UPDATE worker_data
    SET "first_col" = %(f_col)s, "second_col" = %(s_col)s, "third_col" = %(t_col)s, "fourth_col" = %(fo_col)s
    WHERE alt_id = %(a_id)s
    """
    insert_query = """
    INSERT INTO worker_data("first_col", "second_col", "third_col", "fourth_col", "alt_id")
    VALUES (%(f_col)s, %(s_col)s, %(t_col)s, %(fo_col)s, %(a_id)s);
    """
    row_count = 0
    for d in data:
        params = {
            "f_col": d["first_col"],
            "s_col": d["second_col"],
            "t_col": d["third_col"],
            "fo_col": d["fourth_col"],
            "a_id": d["alt_id"]
        }
        with db.connect() as conn:
            has_updated = conn.execute(update_query, params).rowcount
            has_inserted = 0
            if has_updated == 0:
                has_inserted = conn.execute(insert_query, params).rowcount
            row_count += (has_inserted + has_updated)
    return row_count
```

My unit test is currently like so:

```
@patch("api.db.engine")
def test_update_c_data(mock_engine, update_data_dict):
    cursor_mock = mock_engine.connect.return_value.__enter__.return_value
    cursor_mock.execute.return_value.rowcount = 1
    actual_row_count = update_substance_store(mock_engine, update_data_dict)
    assert actual_row_count == 4
```

When I run this unit test, it asserts true, however this will only ever execute the first query (`update_query`) and will never enter the `has_update == 0` block due to returning value of `.rowcount` equalling 1.
So according to the [mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) I should use side_effect. I then create a list of values for the side_effect and use parameterize.
My desired operation would then to be run first the `update_query` and then the insert_query.

I then changed my unit test to use side_effect so it becomes like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parameterize("expected_row_count", [
    ([1, 0]),
    ([0, 1]),
])
@patch("api.db.engine")
def test_update_c_data(mock_engine, expected_row_count, update_data_dict):
    cursor_mock = mock_engine.connect.return_value.__enter__.return_value
    cursor_mock.execute.return_value.rowcount.side_effect = expected_row_count 
    actual_row_count = update_substance_store(mock_engine, update_data_dict)
    assert actual_row_count == 5
```

However when I run this test, it just sets the value to a mock object. Is `side_effect` the correct way to handle this test case?

Comment: As you say, this is multiple question in one, and it looks like opinion based. Can you make one question per post, and about opinion, SO is not the place. You can go in [chat] to discuss with other pythoneers and have opinion.

Comment: @DorianTurba So should I close the question and then ask in the chat? How comes (either of the two questions) would classify as opinion based? I thought there would be one solution (out of what I have already tried/written in the question) for each.

Comment: first, split and clarify your questions. Then, we will see if it can be answer properly :)

Comment: Why are you wanting to mock the database library? Do you already have tests that hit a real database (e.g. one running in Docker)? If not, why not?